# Maximize "sudoku" occurrences in a sudoku

Tags: optimization, sudoku, word-search

How often at most can "Sudoku" occur in a valid (9x9) sudoku?

- create a valid sudoku
- replace (all occurrences of) 5 of the numbers by the 5 letters in "sudoku". (and leave the other numbers untouched)
- count the occurrences of "Sudoku" - consecutive in a straight line: i.e. horizontal, vertical or diagonal in any direction.

What is the maximum count achievable?

Comment: Is it allowed to replace a sixth letter with a second 'U'? Some novelty sudokus do feature repeated values in their number sets. Or are you strictly interested in replacing only 5 of the numbers for uniqueness?

Comment: I assume you mean 6th number? Then no, the idea is that the sudoku rules still apply especially one u in in each row/column/block.

Comment: Is this question about the answer being rot13(rvgure guerr be sbhe)?

Comment: @DL33 That would indeed be the hard part

Comment: Do the letters have to be consecutive along the line?

Comment: @user1502040 yes (added in body)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the $9$ symbols be S, U, D, O, K, !, @, #, and \$.
Because of the repeated U, we need only consider the $4$ diagonal directions and $4(1+2+3+4+3+2+1)=64$ possible placements.  Via integer linear programming with a binary decision variable $x_{ijk}$ to indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ contains symbol $k$ and a binary decision variable $y_{ijvw}$ to indicate whether "sudoku" starts in cell $(i,j)$ and goes in direction $(v,w)$, the maximum number of occurrences of "sudoku" is

> 3.

> \begin{matrix} \# &\color{red}S &! &K &$ &@ &D &U &O &\\ $ &D &\color{red}U &\color{blue}S &! &O &K &@ &\# &\\ @ &K &O &\color{red}D &\color{blue}U &\# &S &! &$ &\\ \color{orange}S &@ &K &U &\color{red}O &\color{blue}D &\# &$ &! &\\ ! &\color{orange}U &\# &$ &S &\color{red}K &\color{blue}O &D &@ &\\ O &$ &\color{orange}D &\# &@ &! &\color{red}U &\color{blue}K &S &\\ K &! &$ &\color{orange}O &D &S &@ &\# &\color{blue}U &\\ U &\# &S &@ &\color{orange}K &$ &! &O &D &\\ D &O &@ &! &\# &\color{orange}U &$ &S &K & \end{matrix}

---

It is clear that no two occurrences can share a U, so even without integer linear programming we have an upper bound of

> $\lfloor 9/2 \rfloor = 4$.

---

By request, here is the SAS code I used:

```
proc optmodel;
   str target = 'SUDOKU';
   set SYMBOLS = /S U D O K '!' '@' '#' '$'/;
   num n = card(SYMBOLS);
   set ROWS = 1..n;
   set COLS = 1..n;
   set CELLS = ROWS cross COLS;
   set DIRECTIONS = {-1,1} cross {-1,1};
   set WORDS = {<i,j> in CELLS, <di,dj> in DIRECTIONS: <i+di*(length(target)-1),j+dj*(length(target)-1)> in CELLS};

   /* X[i,j,k] = 1 if cell <i,j> contains symbol k; 0 otherwise */
   var X {CELLS, SYMBOLS} binary;

   /* Y[i,j,di,dj] = 1 if word starts in cell <i,j> in direction <di,dj>; 0 otherwise */
   var Y {WORDS} binary;

   max NumWords = sum {<i,j,di,dj> in WORDS} Y[i,j,di,dj];

   con OneSymbolPerCell {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in SYMBOLS} X[i,j,k] = 1;
   con RowCon {i in ROWS, k in SYMBOLS}:
      sum {j in COLS} X[i,j,k] = 1;
   con ColCon {j in COLS, k in SYMBOLS}:
      sum {i in ROWS} X[i,j,k] = 1;
   con BoxCon {ri in 1..n by sqrt(n), rj in 1..n by sqrt(n), k in SYMBOLS}:
      sum {i in ri..ri+sqrt(n)-1, j in rj..rj+sqrt(n)-1} X[i,j,k] = 1;
   con WordImpliesSymbol {<i,j,di,dj> in WORDS, k in 1..length(target)}:
      Y[i,j,di,dj] <= X[i+di*(k-1),j+dj*(k-1),char(target,k)];

   solve;

   str sol {ROWS, COLS};
   for {<i,j> in CELLS} do;
      for {k in SYMBOLS: X[i,j,k] > 0.5} do;
         sol[i,j] = k;
         leave;
      end;
   end;
   print sol;
quit;
```

---

If you ignore the extra four symbols and relax all the $=1$ constraints to $\le 1$ so that *at most* one symbol can appear per cell and each symbol can appear *at most* once per row/column/box, the maximum turns out to be

> still 3.

If you further relax the problem by omitting the $\le 1$ box constraints except for U, the maximum turns out to be

> still 3.

If you further relax the problem by omitting all the box constraints, the maximum turns out to be

> 4.

Comment: "Integer linear programming says" without any reference to the particular program is an [appeal to authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority), and as such, not a valid argument.

Comment: @Bass I can provide the objective and constraints if you want, but the usual sudoku constraints are well-known and the additional constraints are straightforward given the decision variables I defined.

Comment: "My friend who is very good at sudoku says 3 is the maximum, and everyone knows the rules of sudoku anyway." (Please do share the code, because otherwise your answer is no better than this ridiculous oversimplification.)

Comment: (Although I would _much_ prefer an English language explanation on why the U's will necessarily collide even though there seems to be plenty of room for them in the grid). (Or in yet other words: knowing the answer is one thing. Knowing that the answer is correct is another. Knowing _why_ the answer is correct is the important bit.)

Comment: @Bass I don't see a good way to explain it. Because they're diagonal, they can't line up at the same U (because then there'd be duplicates in rows or columns), and there isn't enough space to line up at different Us. You can see this by trying it.

Comment: Regardless of which U's are overlapping, the other U's would share a row or column.

Comment: Although I agree with the remarks of @Bass , I did not add a no-computer tag and this is a decent answer. So waiting 3 days seems enough to give the mark...

Comment: I was also expecting to see some no-computer solution.  Did you have one in mind when you posed the question?